# Calculate Field in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, network-analyst

I have the following Model, that runs the Location-Allocation of Network Analyst.

I'm having a problem, in the "Calculate Field Tool". First I add a new field (it's running good) and then I'm my model breaks, when it runs the "Calculate Field Tool".

The expression I'm using is:

```
New_field = %Name%
```

What I'm intending to do is to set the content of my variable "Name" retrieved from the Iterate Feature and write it in my new field.

However, I'm having a problem with that, resulting in a dialog box (see image below)

I checked the content of the "Name" variable and it contains the name I want and it's a text string. I don't know why it is not writing it to my new field (which is also a TEXT field)

Do you have a hint of what's going on?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the length of the current value in `%Name%` larger than the field length?

Comment: No, the %Name% is about 10 characters (maximum) and my field is set to 50 char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out that is needed to put in quotes the expression,

So the correct way is:

```
New_field = "%Name%"
```